# Show preloader only once per session

Tags: jquery, cookies, preloader

Ive been trying some answers on similiar questions but I've not managed to get it to work. I've got the script below witch shows a preloader on the homepage everytime, and I want only to show once per session or the cache is cleared.

Any Help will be much appreciated!

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery("#status").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
  jQuery("#preloader").delay(2500).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('dontLoad') == null)
    {
      jQuery("#status").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
      jQuery("#preloader").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
      sessionStorage.setItem('dontLoad', 'true');
    }
});
```

The [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) property allows you to access a session Storage object. sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage, the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.

[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/yj4thbcv/1/)